# How to correctly send doubles from service to activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, double

How do I send a double value from a service to my main activity via intent, and then set this value as the text for a button in my main activity? I have tried the 
`Double double = Double.parseDouble(""+intent.getExtras().get("TEXT"));`.
This works in the emulator but on my actual phone the program crashes.

This is called everytime a locationManager is updated in the service:

```
Intent i = new Intent("update");
i.putExtra("TEXT", String.format("%f" ,double));
sendBroadcast(i);
```

This is the receiving part:

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(broadcastReceiver == null)   {
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String receivedVal;//I want this to be a double instead
                    receivedVal = (String) intent.getExtras().get("TEXT");
                    Btn.setText(""+receivedVal);
                }
            };
        }
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("update"));
    }
```

Comment: You need to do it via `Intent`? I would just bind to the service. See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send directly a double value within an intent using the method putExtra() and passing a double value (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20double))

To get the value back you can use the getDoubleExtra() method
(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDoubleExtra(java.lang.String,%20double))